# Was it once possible to put a 1x1 round into a minifig cup?

Tags: piece-information, compatibility, piece-usage

[image: cup connection]

I remember being able to put a 1x1 round brick into the top of a minifig cup before my dark age (the period of time that a person stops building with Lego, up to the time they pick up the bricks again), but I have tried it since and can't do it.

Was I imagining that connection, or have they redesigned the minifigure cup?

Is/was there another connection that I might have confused with the minifig cup?

(This would have been sometime in the 80's, but the bricks in my collection went back to the '70s.)

Comment: As the two given answers attest, I was indeed imagining this.

Comment: I remember this too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I still have cups and 1x1 round bricks from the late 70's and I can ensure you these were never brickable like you suggest.

In the 80's, another popular build from Lego was composed of a transparent cup on top of a transparent minifig head. Here is a colored example of that build.

[image]

Comment: That's the answer, after 15 years the memory gets a bit foggy.

Answer (score 13):

Is it possible that you are thinking of this goblet (2343)?

[image: 2343]

This part was fairly common, and it was introduced around 1985, so it was probably in your collection.

1x1 round plates attach securely to the top as shown in this lamp from the Pet Shop:

[image: Pet Shop lamp]

Answer (score 4):

As the others mention, I don't think it was ever possible. Like the goblet part mentioned above, another possibility is that you were putting them in the sauce pan (#4529) which first appeared in 1983. Scala cups (#33054) will also fit one but they didn't appear until 1997.  I think these dates are correct, I know someone will correct me if not :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion (although it may not have the desired result of being able to stack more on top) but I believe you could flip the 1x1 round brick upside down and put the top into the cup hole. If I had the pieces readily available I'd try it.

Comment: Indeed this works, just doesn't "clutch" the stud.